# How to redirect for last page visit DJANGO PYTHON

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

good evening! Hope everything is great!

Well, I have a little problem with redirect in Django, I was trying to make a comment section for my web app but after "posting" the comment, I can only redirect the user to my homepage (through `return redirect ('/')`

Models.py:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,  null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=User)
    responsable = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="author", default=author)
    STATUS_CHOICES = [('D', 'Done'),('P','Doing'),('N','Not done')]
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='N')
    IMPORTANCE_CHOICES = [('H', 'High'),('M','Medium'),('L','Low')]
    importance = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=IMPORTANCE_CHOICES, default='M')
    DEPARTAMENT_CHOICES = [('D', 'Dev'),('M','Marketing'),('H','HR'),('L','Legal'),('F','Finances'),('O','Others')]
    departament = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=DEPARTAMENT_CHOICES, default='M')
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse("task-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,  null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=User)
    body = models.TextField(help_text='Add a comment')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
      ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
      return '%s - %s' % (self.task.title, self.author)
```

Views.py:

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['body']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.task_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.created = timezone.now()
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from .views import (DashboardTaskAppView, 
                    TaskDetailView,
                    TaskCreateView, 
                    TaskUpdateView, 
                    DashboardTaskAppViewPublic,
                    TaskDeleteView,
                    CommentCreate)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index_app, name="home-app"),
    path('task/', DashboardTaskAppView.as_view(), name="task-home"),
    path('task/public', DashboardTaskAppViewPublic.as_view(), name="task-home-public"),
    path('task/new_task/', TaskCreateView.as_view(), name='task-create'),
    path('task/<int:pk>/', TaskDetailView.as_view(), name='task-detail'),
    path('task/<int:pk>/update', TaskUpdateView.as_view(), name='task-update'),
    path('task/<int:pk>/delete', TaskDeleteView.as_view(), name='task-delete'),
    path('task/<int:pk>/comment', CommentCreate.as_view(), name='task-comment'),
    path('docs/', views.doc_taskapp, name="task-doc"),
]
```

What I would like to do is for after submit, to redirect the user for task detail where the comment lies.. I tried `return redirect('task-details')`, but didn't worked. After reading the docs, I think the problem is that I'm trying to access info(data) from Task(model) in Comment(model) and I'm not doing right, is possible to do that? And is possible to call `class CommentCreate(CreateView)` form in a modal? or is absolutely required to have a template.html?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for a redirect to the task detail page with the PK, so:

for function view:
return redirect('task-detail', pk=pk)

Update: for class based view:
return redirect('task-detail', self.kwargs['pk'])

Comment: Hello Ed, thanks for your comment, but It didn't work... when I submit the form I get `NameError at /task/35/comment name 'pk' is not defined`...

Comment: Ah, yes. A different format for class vs formed based views. Glass I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ed Kohler I found out, you gave me the correct line of thought! Thanks!

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
model = Comment
fields = ['body']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.task_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    form.instance.created = timezone.now()
    form.save()
    return redirect('task-detail', pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Thanks again!